# Restrict Parse Cloud Function to be executed only by authenticated users

Tags: node.js, parse-server

Yesterday I tried executing a cloud function from a device without an authenticated user and the function got executed. This is a huge security loophole.

Is there a way to restrict execution of cloud functions to only authenticated users, maybe an option similar to **requiresAuthentication**?

Comment: client will get a token in response to a logon. You could store that on the client and send it as a header.  In your routes you can filter out non authenticated users .

Comment: Hmm sounds interesting although I was looking for a broader solution where I don't have to check the token in every function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `request.user` as stated in the  docs for this purpose. THis is not a 'security loophole'. You can even check for `request.master` if you wanna ensure only a masterKey authenticated call is made.

By default, your API allows communications from any SDK with valid applicationId / clientKey pair. (and applicationId / clientKey are not considered security features but merely routing artifacts).

For more informations, don't hesitate to check on the docs and api docs: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.Cloud.html#.FunctionRequest